Magento 2 : Unable to get the logeed in user data on home page
getting 0 when using use

Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface::getUserId()

on the home page block in cms_index_index.xml layout file.

using below code you can get the logged in user
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink');
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn() == true) 
 {
    //your code.
 } 
?>

NOTE: Inject dependency in your PHP file and remove objectManager.

I need the customerId.

You tried this way to get Customer Id please check reference link
https://meetanshi.com/blog/get-logged-in-customer-data-in-magento-2/
